# Populate jsTree from external JSON file

Tags: jquery, json, file, external, jstree

I've been experimenting with the jQuery.jsTree library and need some help. Please could someone advise me on how to read `json_data` from an external `.json` file.

```
$("#treeDemo").jstree({ 
    "plugins" : [ "themes", "json_data", "ui", "types" ],

    //"json_data": {
    //  "ajax" : {
    //      "url" : "Series.json"
    //  }
    //},

    "json_data" : {
        "data" : [{"data":"Series 1","children":[{"data":"Season 1","children":[{"data":"Episode 1.avi","attr":{"rel":"file"}},{"data":"Episode 2.avi","attr":{"rel":"file"}},{"data":"Episode 3.avi","attr":{"rel":"file"}}],"attr":{"rel":"folder"}},{"data":"Season 2","children":[{"data":"Episode 4.avi","attr":{"rel":"file"}},{"data":"Episode 5.avi","attr":{"rel":"file"}}],"attr":{"rel":"folder"}}],"attr":{"rel":"folder"}},{"data":"Series 2","children":[{"data":"Season 1","children":[{"data":"Episode 1.avi","attr":{"rel":"file"}},{"data":"Episode 2.avi","attr":{"rel":"file"}},{"data":"Episode 3.avi","attr":{"rel":"file"}},{"data":"Episode 4.avi","attr":{"rel":"file"}}],"attr":{"rel":"folder"}}],"attr":{"rel":"folder"}},{"data":"Series 3","children":[{"data":"Episode 1.avi","attr":{"rel":"file"}},{"data":"Episode 2.avi","attr":{"rel":"file"}}],"attr":{"rel":"folder"}},{"data":"Series 1","children":[{"data":"Episode 1.avi","attr":{"rel":"file"}}],"attr":{"rel":"folder"}},{"data":"Series 2","children":[{"data":"Episode 1.avi","attr":{"rel":"file"}},{"data":"Episode 2.avi","attr":{"rel":"file"}}],"attr":{"rel":"folder"}}]
    },

    "types" : {
        "max_depth" : -2,
        "max_children" : -2,
        "valid_children" : ["drive"],
        "types" : {
            "folder" : {
                "valid_children" : ["default", "folder"],
                "icon" : {
                    "image" : "images/folder.png"
                }
            },
            "file" : {
                "valid_children" : "none",
                "icon" : {
                    "image" : "images/file.png"
                }
            }
        }
    },

    "themes" : {
        "theme" : "default",
        "url" : "themes/default/style.css",
        "dots" : true,
        "icons" : true
    },

    "search" : {
        "case_insensitive" : true,
        "ajax" : {
            "url" : "/static/v.1.0pre/_docs/_search_result.json"
        }
    }

})
```

So the above code works as the jsTree should. The commented `json_data` plugin is suppose to read the exact same JSON data from the specified 'Series.json' file however, when the code is run, only the loading gif is displayed.

Please help.

Thanks in advance,
Grant

Answer (score 1):

this seems like a common issue. Anyways,
make an `ajax` call to fetch the required json file as shown below.

```
"json_data":{
    "ajax" : {
        "url" : "info.json"  // the URL to fetch the data. Use relative url if required
     }
}
```

this would definitely work!

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks Teja, I updated my code, and now its simply showing the loading symbol.
The 'Info.json' file is relative to the 'index.html' file thats displaying the tree.

Comment: @Grant ok, then i think the json is not in the required format for jstree. check for missing braces, or missing comma, or unnecessary commas. open up jstree demo and check the json data format there.

Comment: Thanks. I reviewed my JSON data and it was all in order. I've updated my question so there is more information. Please Advise. Thx

Answer (score 1):

I just tried the above examples and they don't work for me. The following in the [github examples code](https://github.com/vakata/jstree/blob/master/demo/basic/index.html), works fine:

```
$('#ajax').jstree({
    'core' : {
        'data' : {
            "url" : "./root.json",
            "dataType" : "json" // needed only if you do not supply JSON headers
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please advise if anyone had it worked. I'm having the same issue as originally Grant was having and none of the suggestions worked for me.
The html and json files are located in the Desktop folder. Provided my json and jstree code here. Thank you for your valuable time and solutions!!

```
$("#DocumentorTree").jstree({

            "core": {
                //"themes": {
                //    "responsive": false
                //},
                // check_callback is set as true to enable the context menu (CREATE, DELETE, ETC.)
                // data source is currently hard-coded for demo purpose. Will need to work with a JSON source for dynamic changes of data.
                //"check_callback": true,
                "data":

                {
                
                            "url": "path.json",
                    "dataType": "JSON" // needed only if you do not supply JSON headers
                }
                        
                    
            },
            "types": {
                "default": {
                    "icon": "fa fa-folder text-primary"
                },
                "file": {
                    "icon": "fas fa-file  text-primary"
                }
            },
            "search": {
                "case_insensitive": true,
                "show_only_matches": true
            },
            "state": { "key": "demo2" },
            "plugins": ["json_data", "contextmenu", "checkbox", "search", "state", "types"]
            // These plugins help with the context menu at right-click, adding checkboxes to each item, search functionality

        });
```

DATA IN JSON FILE:

```
[
```

{
"id": 1,
"text": "Root node 2",
"state": {
"opened": true,
"selected": true
},
"children": [
{
"id": 2,
"text": "Child 1"
},
"Child 2"
]
}
]

Comment: Reiterating a problem statement is not considered a solution.